# Code updating all the rows in a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have two variables `uni_transactions` and `grouped_transactions which has the following values.
[image]

and `grouped_transactions`:
[image]

I'm trying to create a 2-D array, where for each uni_transaction `i`, `trans_dict[i]` has the value `True` in indices `grouped_transactions[i]`.
For ex:

```
trans_dict[0] = [12359, False, **True**, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
trans_dict[1] = [12362, False, False, False, False, False, False, **True**, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

I wrote the following code to achieve this:

```
trans_dict = [[False]*18]*200000
for i in range(200000):
    for j in grouped_transactions[uni_transactions[i]]:
        trans_dict[i][j+1] = True
        trans_dict[i][0] = uni_transactions[i]
```

However, the value is being updated in all the rows instead of only 1 row as expected. Here is the output after 3 iterations:
[image]

At the end, all values in the `trans_dict` will be updated to the last value in `uni_columns`.
Is there any better way to do this.